# Laravel Postgres multischema DB migrations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I am using Postgres and Laravel 5.8. My database has multiple schemas. Each schema has a `patients` table. I am creating authentication for the patients in each schema by adding a password column in the existing patient's table. The migration loops through each schema and should add the password column if it doesn't exist. The migration is created successfully in my console and the migrations table, but not in the database table. I have tried several attempts but still nothing. Any advice on what I may be doing wrong will be appreciated.

**Migration**

```php
class UpdatePatientsAuthentication extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $facilities = Facility::all();

        foreach ($facilities as $facility) {
            $search_path = $facility['schema_name'];
            DB::statement("SET search_path = $search_path");
            if (Schema::hasTable('patients')) {
                Schema::table('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->string('password')->nullable();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $table->dropColumn('password');
    }
}
```

Comment: `SET search_path TO $search_path` perhaps? If you say each schema has a `patients` table, why check for it? Also you won't be able to roll back, `$table` is undefined in your `down()` method.

Comment: @miken32 check if each schema has a patients table because there is a schema with master data that doesnt include a patients table